# pythonic way for partwise max in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, max

I am wondering if there is a fast way to compute a partwise maximum in a numpy array. Example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

If we fix the part size to 3, I would want the answer to be:

```
b = [3,6,9]
```

where 3 is the maximum of the first part of a, `[1,2,3]`, 6 is the maximum of the second part `[4,5,6]` and so on..

Comment: Are the partitions always the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reshaping, then taking the maximum:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> a.reshape((len(a) / 3, 3)).max(axis=1)
array([3, 6, 9])
```

If the array's length is not divisible by the number, your question needs more definition to say what you mean in this case.

**Edit** @ajcr in the comments below shows a much better way to reshape:

```
>>> a.reshape((-1, 3)).max(axis=1)
```

Comment: Your'e answer is correct but the division by 3 should be in the first element of the shape, or change the max to use axis=0.

Comment: You could also just write `-1` instead of `len(a) / 3` (and if you're using Python 3, NumPy complains about the floating point number given to `reshape`).

Comment: @ajcr Many thanks! I did not know that. Will update.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a numpy array, you can reshape it to the part size as row length, now you have a 2d matrix, you can do row/column max.

Edit1: Took ajcr comment and added it to the code.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
a = a.reshape((-1, 3))
print a.max(1)
```

Output:

```
[ 3  6  9 12]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Franchi