# Numpy method to get max value of numpy array for multiple ranges

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get the maximum and minimum value from a numpy array over multiple ranges. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253716/pythonic-way-for-partwise-max-in-a-numpy-array) solution for getting only the maximum over multiple ranges when the ranges are uniform. However, my ranges are not always uniform.

So if there is an array that has the numbers 1-9 and the ranges are the indices `[0-2], [3-6], [7-8]`, I would like to get the max and min value from each range.

I have posted a possible solution below, but I wonder if numpy has a method to do this without a loop.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
slices = [np.arange(0,3), np.arange(3,7), np.arange(7,9)]

max = np.empty(0)
min = np.empty(0)
for slice in slices:
    max = np.concatenate([max, np.max(a[slice])])
    min = np.concatenate([min, np.min(a[slice])])

min_and_max = np.concatenate([min,max])
```

Comment: Does your code work? I didn't realize `np.ndarray` objects had the `concatenate` method as an attribute ([relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58485131/numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-concatenate-error)). Also looks like a mismatch of dims?

Comment: Also, a series of concatenations with numpy arrays is significantly less efficient than using a python list, appending, then casting to a `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Use a straight forward list append or list comprehension.  Don't try to be "pythonic" especially if you don't know what that means.

Comment: I fixed the concatenate and thanks for pointing out the inefficiencies of concatenating. These comments helped me clarify what I was really trying to ask: "Is a `numpy` method that could operate on the list of slices?" That way I could avoid using a loop and repeated concatenation and the inherent inefficiency of repeated concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ufunc.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) is precisely for this:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> slices = np.array([0, 3, 7])
>>> np.maximum.reduceat(a, slices)
array([3, 7, 9])
>>> np.minimum.reduceat(a, slices)
array([1, 4, 8])
>>> np.vstack([np.minimum.reduceat(a, slices),
...            np.maximum.reduceat(a, slices)])
array([[1, 4, 8],
       [3, 7, 9]])
```